# How can I exclude elements which aren't visible from a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I have a form elements with checkbox containing the "nickname" toggle field. I am validating that all of the fields aren't blank, and enabling a button on the page after all fields have had values entered.

However, I have some input fields which aren't visible to the user because they're inside `<div>` elements which have the `display:none;` CSS property. How can I exclude these elements in jQuery and only perform the validation on the fields which are visible?

HTML

```
<input name="cvv" type="text">
<span class="checkbox"></span>
<p>Save this card for faster transactions<br>Note: Your CVV number will not be stored</p> 
<div class="col-md-6 nicknameBlock" id="nickNameToggle">    
    <input name="" type="text" placeholder="Nick Name" class="textbox textbox50 required">
</div>
<div class="row center">
    <a href="javascript:" class="bt btblue disableClick" id="submitBtn">
    <img src="images/icon_pay.png" > PAY</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nicknameBlock{
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
activatePayButton('submitBtn'); 
function activatePayButton(formId){
    $form = $('#'+formId);     
    $form.find(':input').on('change keyup blur', function(event) {
        var disable = false;      
        $form.find("input[type!='hidden']").each(function(i, el) { 

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it clearer what's being asked. If I've misunderstood feel free to rollback or [edit] the post yourself to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple, really

```
if($(".nicknameBlock").is(":visible")) { alert("Im visible now") }
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay!   Lets take it line by line:

```
activatePayButton('submitBtn'); // this is the id of anchor which has img
 function activatePayButton(formId){
     $form = $('#'+formId);  // so this selector selects the anchor not form element   
     $form.find(':input').on('change keyup blur', function(event) { 
    // as $form is an anchor which has only img as child
    // you don't have any input to bind any event on it
       var disable = false;      
       $form.find("input[type!='hidden']").each(function(i, el) { 
          // that is why this doesn't get executed.
       });
     });
 }
```

Comment: my form containing two or more hidden fields.. that's why i did the check i.e(<input type="hidden" value=""/>

Comment: can you post a fiddle with all your respective form and form elements?

Comment: @vishnu That part is fine, but you still need to address the other issues Jai has pointed out with your code. There's also still the main problem (excluding the elements which aren't visible to the user) to solve, which NachoDawg's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32478974/552438) shows you how to do.